# See which UICollectionView layout is set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I was wondering if it's possible to change the layout of my `UICollectionViewCell`s based on the layout set in the `UICollectionView`.

So is it possible to get the layout set?

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` has a variable `collectionViewLayout`.
If you keep a weak reference to your collection view in the cell you can set it in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method and check it's value in `willDisplayCell` delegate method and update cell's layout accordingly, i.e. write a method to update cell layout in the custom class and call that method in `willDisplayCell` for each cell...

However, if the cell's layout is going to change a lot,  I think a better way of doing this would be to create separate custom cells for each layout and depending on the collection view's `collectionViewLayout` return the relevant cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` ..

In any case, just make sure to call the `reloadData` method when layout is changed..